# Excel - Match cell values in 2 separate columns and paste a different value if match

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-match

```
=INDEX(C:C,MATCH(A1,B:B,0))
```

The above formula is being pasted in `D1`.

I need it to return the `C` cell that on the same row as the matching `A` and `B` fields:

```
A       B        C            D

77      22       MO91117
88      88       MO91337
99      99       MO12347
22      77       MO91837
```

Ideally, if I ran the formula in `D1`, it would return `M091837`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The formula looks perfect. What's the problem/question?

Comment: I keep receiving #N/A

Comment: A guess... One of your columns A or B (or some cells inside) are formatted as Text. Select columns A and B and format cells as `Number` with 0 decimals..

Comment: Brilliant! That seems to have fixed the problem! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @A.S.H if you externalize your one-liner comment to a valid answer just to help the bot marking answered questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering for completeness. Credit to [A.S.H](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4926357/a-s-h) for the answer (in the comments of the question).

Ensure that both columns that you are trying to match are formatted similarly. It looks like the error in this question was that one column was formatted as text, and one column was formatted as a number. As an example the number 4 and the character 4 are represented differently in software, thus not returning expected values when trying to match text and numbers.